# Lost "OpenShift Origin" variant install option upgrading to atomic-openshift-installer 3.6

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have a CentOS 7.3 machine with all the requirements (hopefully) and updated.

I launch `atomic-openshift-installer` and it only proposes 2 options:

```
(1) OpenShift Container Platform 
(2) Registry
```

I expected:

```
(1) OpenShift Origin 
(2) OpenShift Container Platform 
(3) Registry
```

It used to work with the previous version: atomic-openshift-utils-3.5

**What should I do to have "OpenShift Origin" variant available in version 3.6 ? **

Info:

- CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
- origin-3.6.0-1.0.c4dd4cf.x86_64
- openshift-ansible-3.6.173.0.3-1.el7.noarch
- atomic-openshift-utils-3.6.173.0.3-1.el7.noarch

I have the repo "CentOS-OpenShift-Origin" installed:

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-OpenShift-Origin.repo 
[CentOS-OpenShift-Origin]
name=CentOS-OpenShift-Origin
enabled=1
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/paas/x86_64/openshift-origin/
```

If it helps, you can look at my kickstart file: https://github.com/BrunoVernay/VM-images-packer/blob/master/kickstart/centos-openshift-master.ks.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the "origin" variant is not displayed in version 3.6.173, but is still supported (if you specify "origin" via a config file for example).

It should come back in a next version as my pull request has been accepted: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/pull/5132